# Why can't I reference scoped aggregates in the WHERE or HAVING clauses?

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed that BQL won't allow me to reference scoped aggregates in either the WHERE or HAVING clauses. For example:

```
% bq query 'SELECT fullName, COUNT(children.name) WITHIN RECORD as numChildren FROM [persons.person]'  
+---------------+-------------+
|   fullName    | numChildren |
+---------------+-------------+
| John Doe      |           2 |
| Mike Jones    |           3 |
| Anna Karenina |           0 |
+---------------+-------------+

% bq query 'SELECT fullName, COUNT(children.name) WITHIN RECORD as numChildren FROM [persons.person] WHERE numChildren > 0'  
BigQuery error in query operation: Field 'numChildren' not found in table 'persons.person'.

% bq query 'SELECT fullName, COUNT(children.name) WITHIN RECORD as numChildren FROM [persons.person] HAVING numChildren > 0' 
BigQuery error in query operation: Invalid use of HAVING clause. HAVING should be used only when non scoped aggregations are present. Non aggregating queries should use WHERE instead
```

I understand the rationale for not allowing group-level aggregates in the WHERE clause, as well as the rationale for not allowing table-level aggregates in either the WHERE or HAVING clauses, but I can't think of any reason whey scoped-aggregates can't appear in the WHERE or HAVING clauses. Can anyone provide a reason?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you should be able to do this in a HAVING clause. This has been added to our internal document of potential BigQuery SQL language improvements.

Comment: In standard SQL you aren't allowed to reference group-level aggregate values in the WHERE clause because the WHERE predicate is applied before grouping occurs, i.e. WHERE is applied before grouping, and HAVING is applied afterwards. Since scoped aggregate values don't depend on grouping it seems like you should be able to reference them in the WHERE predicate as well.

Comment: This makes intuitive sense. I'll see if I can convince the guy driving the language evolution.

Answer (score 0):

Good news: This works now.

```
SELECT created_at, COUNT(payload.shas.actor_email) WITHIN RECORD AS xx
FROM [publicdata:samples.github_nested]
HAVING xx>1
LIMIT 10
```